# Jquery with JSF to Hide text

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I am new to JQuery. I am trying to use jQuery in JSF to hide and show components. Although it can be easily achieved with JSF but still my requirement is to use jQuery to achieve this.

But I am not able to hide any component.
The code snippet is:-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<html> 
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery Effects</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1.js" >

    function showSuccess()
    {
    jquery("#formId\\:showLinkId").click(function(){
        jquery("#formId\\:success").hide('slow',function(){
            alert('Hide Done');
        });
    });
    }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <f:view>
    <h:form id="formId">
    <rich:panel header="Jquery" style="position: relative; width: 350px;">
    <h:commandButton id="showLinkId" value="Click Here" onclick="showSuccess()" />

    <h:outputLabel id="success" value="DONE" ></h:outputLabel>
    </rich:panel>
    </h:form>
    </f:view>
    </body>
    </html>
```

However no effect is visible on GUI.
The script file is saved inside WebContent/script.

I even tried including the script in between the pages however again to no use

Please guide me..

Comment: If possible for you, don't use JSP with JSF. Use Facelets! This will keep you sane ;)

Comment: @Mike Braun Possibly we will be migrating to JSF2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 4 problems:

1. You need to declare functions in a separate `<script>` element than the one where a script file is loaded.
2. The function name `jquery()` is wrong. Is should be `jQuery()`.
3. During `onclick` you're calling a function which in turn attaches a new click event handler to the button, but this is in turn not invoked at all.
4. The `<h:commandButton>` fires by default a POST request, but you are not blocking it in any way.

There are basically 2 ways to fix your problem:

1. Just call the hide function directly in the `showSuccess()` function and return false in the onclick.

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function showSuccess() {
           jQuery("#formId\\:success").hide('slow',function() {
               alert('Hide Done');
           });
       }
   </script>

   ...

   <h:form id="formId">
       <rich:panel header="Jquery" style="position: relative; width: 350px;">
           <h:commandButton id="showLinkId" value="Click Here" onclick="showSuccess(); return false;" />
           <h:outputText id="success" value="DONE" />
       </rich:panel>
   </h:form>
   ```
2. Remove the onclick function and bind the event handler after document load.

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           jQuery("#formId\\:showLinkId").click(function() {
               jQuery("#formId\\:success").hide('slow',function() {
                   alert('Hide Done');
               });

               return false;
           });
       });
   </script>

   ...

   <h:form id="formId">
       <rich:panel header="Jquery" style="position: relative; width: 350px;">
           <h:commandButton id="showLinkId" value="Click Here" />
           <h:outputText id="success" value="DONE" />
       </rich:panel>
   </h:form>
   ```

Note that those components doesn't necessarily need to be JSF components. The following should work equally good.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#showLinkId").click(function() {
            jQuery("#success").hide('slow',function() {
                alert('Hide Done');
            });
        });
    });
</script>

...

<h:form id="formId">
    <rich:panel header="Jquery" style="position: relative; width: 350px;">
        <button id="showLinkId">Click Here</button>
        <span id="success">DONE</span>
    </rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: This solution did work. Also I figured out that problem was due to script and when I used script src as the one hosted by google the same code ran perfectly without any modifications whatsoever. But is it possible to hide or show a JSF component present inside <a4j:OutputPanel> using JQuery..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1.js" >
```

Change it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Bind the event-handler as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#formId\\:showLinkId").click(function(){
        jQuery("#formId\\:success").hide('slow',function(){
            alert('Hide Done');
        });
    });
});
```

You can remove `onclick="showSuccess()"` from `<h:commandButton id="showLinkId" ...`.

If you are not sure of what client-id is rendered by JSF, you can see the HTML source on the browser. e.g. to make sure that you are using the right id in `jquery("#formId\\:showLinkId")`.

Comment: I assume I dont have to change anything. I used whatever you told.removed src attribute from script and change the event-handler.However still no effect is seen on GUI. Why in first jQuery Q is capital and in other ones its small...Also, I always get a red line under jquery stating function jquery(string) is undefined...

Comment: If i remove showSuccess() from the JSF how will it call this function on click of commandButton...

Comment: Oh sorry I just copied yours. Q is capital.

Comment: After the document is loaded, jQuery binds the event-handler for you.

Comment: @Hukamanata: Sorry forgot to tell you that you need to include the JQuery. Use another `<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>` for that.

Comment: It is still not working..Absolutely no effect on GUI..I just get a command Button and a text...On clicking commandButton nothing is happening.

Comment: Let me tell you what I have done to include .js file.I copied the script code from jQuery website and created a new js file in Eclipse IDE. Copied the entire script code in new js file and names it as jQuery-1.7.1.js.This is the file I am using for Jquery. Is there anything wrong here?